# How to Create Project / Checkout password protected SVN repo using RStudio

Tags: r, svn, rstudio

I'm trying to checkout an existing SVN repo using RStudio.  The repo is password protected but RStudio is only asking for a username.  I go thru the process of:

```
New Project -> Version Control -> Subversion -> Fill in all fields
```

When I hit `Connect` after filling in all the fields, I get the following message (cleaned for identifying IP's):

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://~myIPinfo': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A TLS warning alert has been received. (https://~myIPinfo)
```

I am using Chrome as my browser.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: I've also tried using the follow forms for username:

```
1) username
2) username:password
3) domain\username
4) domain\username:password
```